# Water in duct after installing steam humidifier

Tags: hvac, humidifier

I had a steam humidifier (Aprilaire 800) installed a few weeks ago.  It's controlled by an Ecobee thermostat.  The steam dispersion tube is in a vertical return duct, above the air filter.  Below the filter are the furnace, AC evaporator, and the supply duct (which goes down into the crawl space).  There's also a fresh air inlet that joins the return duct above the steam tube.

A few days ago, I noticed some water leaking from the bottom of the AC evaporator.  I checked the air filter, and it was wet on the same side as the water leak below.  The steam dispersion tube is also on the same side, so it was clearly the culprit.  I turned the humidifier off and let everything dry out for a couple of days.  I didn't see any more water leaking after it dried.  I looked inside the duct, and I verified that the dispersion tube is oriented as described in the installation instructions.

The HVAC company sent a tech out yesterday.  He told me he found a pinhole leak in the steam dispersion tube and patched it with a heat resistant sealant.  I turned the humidifier back on, and noticed water leaking in the same place a few hours later.  The filter is also wet again in the same place.

I called the HVAC company again, and the tech said he wants to move the steam dispersion tube to the supply duct.  Does this sound like the correct fix?  I'm worried that it will continue leaking, but I won't be able to see the water leaking out anymore.  Should I call another company for a second opinion?

Comment: I'm far from an expert on this, but it strikes me as likely that _steam_ will condense into liquid water as it escapes from the inlet. Especially if the return air duct is cool, as it normally would be (room temp air is quite cool in comparison to the temperature of steam). I'm sure there's a proper way of dealing with this so it doesn't get everything wet, though, and it seems that they just haven't done the proper thing.

Comment: `found a pinhole leak in the steam dispersion tube` ... that sounds like a story ... doesn't the tube have some holes already?

Comment: @jsotola The holes are all supposed to point up, so any condensation in the tube will safely run back down to the humidifier.  But, I also wonder if he made up that story just to buy some time.  I'm going to have to look at the tube again to see if it looks patched.

Comment: i do not know anything about a steam humidifier ... common sense tells me that the steam must be introduced only when the main furnace blower is running and it should be introduced to the outgoing duct ... the main blower should run for some time after the steam is turned off, so that the ducts have time to dry ... otherwise the condensation will be evident

Comment: Is the unit only commanded to run while the air handler is running? 
I have seen this problem on more than a few systems if there is no air flow sensor the moisture builds up and puddles or that has been a failure mode I have observed

Comment: The thermostat always turns the blower on when it calls for steam.

Comment: I looked at the dispersion tube, and I saw that the tech put some red sealant around the perimeter of the tube, right where it enters the duct.  I wonder if he's now thinking that there's not enough space in that part of the duct for the steam to disperse?  Not sure.  But if it is a leak, I imagine it would still leak after it's moved.

Comment: The steam tube is about 14 inches above the filter.

Answer (score 1):

The Aprilaire manual has a table of straight-line steam absorption distances required. It is a function of airflow speed. If there is not enough distance, the steam will condense.